# Measure of preimage of a surjective continuous function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.
We suppose that $f$ is surjective and continuous (say for the Euclidean norm).

If $r>0$ and $x \in \mathbb R^2$, denote $D(x,r) =\{y \in \mathbb R^2 ~|~ ||x-y||<r  \}$.

It seems true that $f^{-1}(D(x,r))$ is of positive measure, but how to prove it?

Comment: Hint:$f^{-1}(D(x,r))$ is open and nonempty so it contains a open disk which has positive measure already.

Comment: That's quite a strong hint :p

Comment: Indeed, thanks.